Accessing or Intecepting HTTP Request & Response from apps running in iFrame
I have a requirement where we display multiple applications of different domains in iframes within a webpage. We do have permission to access all the API's but we are not allowed to touch the code base of these applications,
In our main application we are ought to track the activities happening within these apps in iframe I went through some forums about this and most of them required changing the code of the child applications.
I saw something like easyXDM but not sure if that's the correct approach. Let me know the possible way to perform. Thanks in Advance.

If the iframes are in a different domain, the main application has no access to what they're doing.
